# Update rosources using PATCH

Tags: api-design

Given a resource

```
id: string;
name: string;
createdDate: number;
consumedDate: number; // unix
rejectedDate: number;
```

If I have some logic related to rejectedDate, can I use a rest Patch Method to update only rejectedDate?

Like PATCH /resource/:id/rejectedDate

```
body:  { rejectedDate: '2020-01-01' }
```

Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
ROUTE: /resource/:id
METHODE: PATCH
BODY: { rejectedDate: '2020-01-01', .... other fields to update if needed }
```

Actually, the best practice is to have

- GET: `/resources` - for the getting a list
- GET: `/resources/:id` - for the getting by id
- POST: `/resources` - for the creating a new one
- PATCH: `/resources/:id` - for the partially updating
- PUT: `/resources/:id` - for the complete replacement of the item
- DELETE: `/resources/:id` - for removing item by id